# Haskell or Elm error: unknown public key OID

Tags: windows, haskell, x509certificate, elm

I have an error in Windows with Elm:

```
elm-make.exe: unknown public key OID: [1,2,643,2,2,19]
```

Also I have the same with Haskell Platform, because it's an error of `Data.X509.PublicKey` module. How to fix it?

I've found that `1.2.643.2.2.19` is a `GOST R 34.10-2001` encryption algorithm installed with **Crypto PRO** encryption software. How to revert it back to defaults?

Comment: Could you provide more information? Do you get this error every time you try to run elm-make, or do you get it only for specific input files?

Comment: Everytime. I take it after **Crypto Pro** installed. I have no idea how to use "1.2.643.2.2.3" algorithm which is necessary to Haskell. If I reinstall Windows than Haskell and Elm work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirm that it is *likely* CryptoPro. For me, error happened when using `pandoc-citeproc`.

I solved it this way without reinstalling Windows:

1. Removing CryproPro.
2. Then manually removing trusted root certificates using ГОСТ algorithm (they were likely the reason of such a crash) as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788967(v=vs.110).aspx).

Good luck!

P.S. Don't know if Russian ГОСТ certificates actually violate standards in some very bad way or Haskell library does. This is subject to investigate.